# Which jquery form validation plugin you would prefer to add validation without making any change in form's current mark-up?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, xhtml, validation

I'm working on a old and big site where I just need to add form validation on whatever code is for form in the page. I can't edit html of form. I can just add my new css and javascript file. Which jquery plugin I should use?

different class is available on each different form element in source.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any jquery library for form validation and this only require class of each input type which you can add by css.

Please try this

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation